# android developer question

Tags: android, layout

I am looking the R.java file and I saw this under the app_name 0x7f040001. I know that is some kind of encryption because it displays hello world i believe. There are other ones there but I was just wonder what encryption that is.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At compile time, Android generates a class named **`R`** that contains **resource identifiers** to all the resources in your program. This class contains several subclasses, one for each type of resource supported by Android, and for which you provided a resource file.

Each class contains one or more identifiers for the compiled resources, that you use in your code to load the resource. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html).

Answer (score 2):

Those numbers are just unique resource identifiers. No encryption (it wouldn't be possible to encrypt a variable length string and get a 32-bit integer).